# Comparing value of a certain row with all previous rows in data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, grouping

I'm having a dataset containing firms involving in a certain category of products.
Dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.table(year=c(1979,1979,1980,1980,1980,1981,1981,1982,1982,1982,1982),
                 category = c("A","A","B","C","A","D","C","F","F","A","B"))
```

I want to create a new variable as follows:
If a firm enters into a new category that it has not been previously engaged in **previous years (not the same year)**, then that entry is labeld as "NEW", otherwise it will be labeld as "OLD".

As such, the desired outcome will be:

```
    year   category   Newness
 1: 1979        A     NEW
 2: 1979        A     NEW
 3: 1980        B     NEW
 4: 1980        C     NEW
 5: 1980        A     OLD
 6: 1981        D     NEW
 7: 1981        C     OLD
 8: 1982        F     NEW
 9: 1982        F     NEW
10: 1982        A     OLD
11: 1982        B     OLD
```

I'm inclined to use data.table as I have over 1.5 million observations, and want to be able to replicate the solution by grouping by firm IDs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assign the first year as `"NEW"` for each `category`.

```
library(data.table)
df[, Newness := c("NEW", "OLD")[(match(year, unique(year)) > 1) + 1], category]
df

#    year category Newness
# 1: 1979        A     NEW
# 2: 1979        A     NEW
# 3: 1980        B     NEW
# 4: 1980        C     NEW
# 5: 1980        A     OLD
# 6: 1981        D     NEW
# 7: 1981        C     OLD
# 8: 1982        F     NEW
# 9: 1982        F     NEW
#10: 1982        A     OLD
#11: 1982        B     OLD
```

Similarly, in `dplyr` this can be written as :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(Newness =  c("NEW", "OLD")[(match(year, unique(year)) > 1) + 1])
```

Comment: I think that your answer is not right. you obtained the expected output
because the first time that each category appears in the reproducible data
actually coincides with the first year that a firm enters into
that category. It is not guaranteed that this is the case for the entire dataset.
If you change the order of the rows (e.g. `set.seed(2)`; 
`df <- df[sample(nrow(df))]`), you would no longer obtain the
expected output.

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang you can always `order` the data if they are not ordered.

Comment: Yes, but as long as it's not specified that the data is ordered, I don't think that you should assume that it is, and if you do so, then I think that you should explicitly specify that it is necessary to obtain the right result.

Comment: @RonakShah Is there anyway I could restrict to a certain time period? For example, instead of looking through the whole dataset, I'd look for matched in the last 5 years?

Comment: I don't think that's an easy/small fix. Perhaps, ask it as a new question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `duplicated + ifelse` in base R:

```
transform(df,Newness = ifelse(duplicated(category)==duplicated(df),"New","Old"))
    year category Newness
 1: 1979        A     New
 2: 1979        A     New
 3: 1980        B     New
 4: 1980        C     New
 5: 1980        A     Old
 6: 1981        D     New
 7: 1981        C     Old
 8: 1982        F     New
 9: 1982        F     New
10: 1982        A     Old
11: 1982        B     Old
```

in data.table you will do:

```
library(data.table)
df[,Newness := ifelse(duplicated(.SD)==duplicated(category),"New","Old")]
df
    year category Newness
 1: 1979        A     New
 2: 1979        A     New
 3: 1980        B     New
 4: 1980        C     New
 5: 1980        A     Old
 6: 1981        D     New
 7: 1981        C     Old
 8: 1982        F     New
 9: 1982        F     New
10: 1982        A     Old
11: 1982        B     Old
```

Comment: I think that your answer is not right. you obtained the expected output because the first time that each category appears in the reproducible data actually coincides with the first year that a firm enters into that category. It is not guaranteed that this is the case for the entire dataset. If you change the order of the rows (e.g. set.seed(2); df <- df[sample(nrow(df))]), you would no longer obtain the expected output.

Comment: @Onyambu I asked a separate related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926480/comparing-values-of-a-certain-row-with-a-certain-number-of-previous-rows-in-data
I would appreciate if you had any thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve your problem as follows:

```
# Method 1:
setDT(df, key = "year")[, Newness := fifelse(year == year[1L], "NEW", "OLD"), category]  

# Method 2
setDT(df, key = "year")[, Newness := c("NEW", "OLD")[match(year, year[1L], 2)], category]

#      year category Newness
# 1:   1979        A     NEW
# 2:   1979        A     NEW
# 3:   1980        B     NEW
# 4:   1980        C     NEW
# 5:   1980        A     OLD
# 6:   1981        D     NEW
# 7:   1981        C     OLD
# 8:   1982        F     NEW
# 9:   1982        F     NEW
# 10:  1982        A     OLD
# 11:  1982        B     OLD
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could restrict to a certain time period? For example, instead of looking through the whole dataset, I'd look for matched in the last 5 years?

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option:

```
df[, Newness := "OLD"][
    unique(df, by="category"), on=.(year, category), Newness := "NEW"]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1.5e6
df <- data.table(year=sample(1970:2019, nr, TRUE), category=sample(1e4, nr, TRUE))
setkey(df, year, category)

mtd0 <- function()
    df[, Newness := c("NEW", "OLD")[(match(year, unique(year)) > 1) + 1], category]

mtd1 <- function() 
    df[, Newness := ifelse(duplicated(.SD)==duplicated(category),"New","Old")]

mtd2 <- function()
    df[, Newness := "OLD"][
        unique(df, by="category"), on=.(year, category), Newness := "NEW"]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=3L,
    mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2())
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd0() 154.6129 167.5908 182.70500 180.5687 196.7511 212.9334     3
 mtd1() 343.3772 375.0303 395.08653 406.6835 420.9412 435.1989     3
 mtd2()  41.4178  42.0520  45.40527  42.6862  47.3990  52.1118     3
```

Comment: I think that your answer is not right. Since the first year in
the dataset that you generated is 1970, we expect all intances 
of the variable `Newness` to be `New` in 1970 (there is no previous year!).
If you use the output generated by your code to tabulate 
the variable `Newness` in 1970, you will find that some instances take on
the value `OLD` (and this should not be the case since there no old category in 1970!).
For instance, `mtd2()[year==1970, .N, Newness]` gives 775 NEW intances 
and 29103 OLD intances!!
Further, all your output are not the same.

Comment: If you apply your code on the reproducible dataset, you would
accidentally get the expected output; but, that would be due to the fact
that the first time that each category appears in the reproducible data
actually coincides with the first year that a firm enters into
that category; and it is not guaranteed that this is the case for the entire dataset.

Comment: Ah I got what you meant. Data needs to be sorted

Comment: @chinsoon12 Is there anyway I could restrict to a certain time period? For example, instead of looking through the whole dataset, I'd look for matched in the last 5 years?

Comment: @chinsoon12. Thanks for the answer. I asked it as a separate question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926480/comparing-values-of-a-certain-row-with-a-certain-number-of-previous-rows-in-data

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but since efficiency was a concern, I thought of posting the comparison between different methods. This is run on a patent database I'm working on.

```
> Ronak <- function()
+   df[, Newness := c("NEW", "OLD")[(match(year, unique(year)) > 1) + 1], category]
> B._Christian1 <- function()
+   df[, Newness := fifelse(year == year[1L], "NEW", "OLD"), category]
> B._Christian2 <- function()
+   df[, Newness := c("NEW", "OLD")[match(year, year[1L], 2)], category]
> Onyambu <- function()
+   df[,Newness := ifelse(duplicated(.SD)==duplicated(category),"New","Old")]
> chinsoon12 <- function()
+   df[, Newness := "OLD"][unique(df, by="category"), on=.(year, category),
+                                     Newness := "NEW"]
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=3L,
+                                Ronak(), B._Christian1(), B._Christian2(), Onyambu(), chinsoon12())
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
         Ronak()  482.6191  482.7456  484.3963  482.8720  485.2849  487.6977     3
 B._Christian1()  240.3175  242.9452  243.9646  245.5729  245.7881  246.0033     3
 B._Christian2()  274.8113  278.3835  279.7271  281.9557  282.1850  282.4142     3
       Onyambu() 2374.6428 2377.0848 2379.3771 2379.5267 2381.7442 2383.9617     3
    chinsoon12()  200.6551  200.8337  202.5799  201.0123  203.5423  206.0723     3
```

Thanks all again.