# Comparing values of a certain row with a certain number of previous rows in data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, rows

This is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460933/comparing-value-of-a-certain-row-with-all-previous-rows-in-data-table) asked before.

In a database containing firm and category values, I want to calculate this:
If a firm enters into a new category that it has not been previously engaged in ***Three(3)*** previous years (not including the same year), then that entry is labeld as "NEW", otherwise it will be labeld as "OLD".

In the following dataset:

```
df <- data.table(year=c(1979,1979,1980,1980,1981,1981,1982,1983,1983,1984,1984),
                 category = c("A","A","B","C","A","D","F","F","C","A","B"))
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
 year category Newness
 1: 1979        A     NEW
 2: 1979        A     NEW
 3: 1980        B     NEW
 4: 1980        C     NEW
 5: 1981        A     NEW
 6: 1981        D     NEW
 7: 1982        F     NEW
 8: 1983        F     OLD
 9: 1983        C     OLD
10: 1984        A     OLD
11: 1984        B     NEW
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Edited the dataframe.

Comment: should row 5 be OLD instead of NEW?

Comment: @chinsoon12 It would under the old example. With the updated df, the firm has not been involved in the B category in the last three years (1981,1982,1983), and thus is NEW. Your codes work just fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options.

**1)** Using non-equi self join with `mult`

```
df[, yrsago := year - 3L]
df[, Newness := 
    c("OLD", "NEW")[1L + df[df, on=.(category, year>=yrsago, year<year), mult="first", is.na(x.category)]]
]
```

**2)** Using non-equi self join with `by=.EACHI`:

```
df[, yrsago := year - 3L]
df[, Newness2 := 
    c("OLD", "NEW")[1L + df[df, on=.(category, year>=yrsago, year<year), by=.EACHI, .N==0L]$V1]
]
```

**3)** Using a rolling join which should be the fastest

```
df[, q := year - 0.1]
df[, Newness3 := 
    df[df, on=.(category, year=q), roll=3L, fifelse(is.na(x.year), "NEW", "OLD")]
]
```

output:

```
    year category yrsago Newness Newness2      q Newness3
 1: 1979        A   1976     NEW      NEW 1978.9      NEW
 2: 1979        A   1976     NEW      NEW 1978.9      NEW
 3: 1980        B   1977     NEW      NEW 1979.9      NEW
 4: 1980        C   1977     NEW      NEW 1979.9      NEW
 5: 1981        A   1978     OLD      OLD 1980.9      OLD
 6: 1981        D   1978     NEW      NEW 1980.9      NEW
 7: 1982        F   1979     NEW      NEW 1981.9      NEW
 8: 1983        F   1980     OLD      OLD 1982.9      OLD
 9: 1983        C   1980     OLD      OLD 1982.9      OLD
10: 1984        A   1981     OLD      OLD 1983.9      OLD
11: 1984        B   1981     NEW      NEW 1983.9      NEW
```

data:

```
df <- data.table(year=c(1979,1979,1980,1980,1981,1981,1982,1983,1983,1984,1984),
    category = c("A","A","B","C","A","D","F","F","C","A","B"))
```

Comment: Rolling joiint is indeed the fastest. Anyway I could iterate it by groups(firms)?

Comment: Yeah just add group in the on argument

Comment: Thanks. It's insane fast!

Answer (score 1):

Using `mapply` :

```
df$Newness <- c('NEW', 'OLD')[mapply(function(x, y) any(y == df$category
                [df$year < x & df$year >= (x - 3)]), df$year, df$category) + 1]
df

#    year category Newness
# 1: 1979        A     NEW
# 2: 1979        A     NEW
# 3: 1980        B     NEW
# 4: 1980        C     NEW
# 5: 1980        A     OLD
# 6: 1981        D     NEW
# 7: 1981        F     NEW
# 8: 1982        F     OLD
# 9: 1982        C     OLD
#10: 1982        A     OLD
#11: 1982        B     OLD
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but just posting the time benchmark for the solutions offered, applied on a portion of the patent database I'm working on:

```
> df[, yrsago := year - 3L]
> df[, q := year - 0.1]
> tbench <- bench::mark(time_unit="s",
+                     sol_1 = df[, Newness := c('NEW', 'OLD')[mapply(function(x, y) any(y == df$category[df$year < x & df$year >= (x - 3)]), df$year, df$category) + 1]],
+                    sol_2 = 
+                      df[, Newness := c("OLD", "NEW")[1L + df[df, on=.(category, year>=yrsago, year<year), mult="first",
+                                                              is.na(x.category)]]],
+                    sol_3 = df[, Newness2 := c("OLD", "NEW")[1L + df[df, on=.(category, year>=yrsago, year<year),
+                                                                     by=.EACHI, .N==0L]$V1]],
+                    
+                    sol_4 = 
+                      df[, Newness3 := df[df, on=.(category, year=q), roll=3L, fifelse(is.na(x.year), "NEW", "OLD")]],
+                    
+                    min_time = 1
+ )
> 
> tbench
# A tibble: 4 x 13
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result       memory      time    gc     
  <bch:expr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>      <dbl> <list>       <list>      <list>  <list> 
1 sol_1      0.144   0.192        5.53     321MB     1.11     5     1      0.905 <data.table~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:t~ <tibbl~
2 sol_2      0.00611 0.00629    159.       406KB     1.09   146     1      0.921 <data.table~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:t~ <tibbl~
3 sol_3      0.00632 0.00647    154.       406KB     1.07   144     1      0.936 <data.table~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:t~ <tibbl~
4 sol_4      0.00405 0.00416    238.       393KB     0      238     0      1.00  <data.table~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:t~ <tibbl~
```

Thanks all for your help.